# How to use `Which` in FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm using fluent assertions and I have this test:

```
result.Should().NotBeNull();
result.Link.Should().Equals("https://someinvoiceurl.com");
```

which works fine but when I try this

```
result.Should().NotBeNull()
.Which.Link.Equals("https://someinvoiceurl.com");
```

I got this error

> 'AndConstraint' does not contain a definition for 'Which' and no accessible extension method 'Which' accepting a first argument of type 'AndConstraint' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `And` instead of `Which`. The former is used for chaining. The latter is when the previous assertion changes the type of the object that is being asserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `.NotBeNull()` is not generic (it is an extension on `ObjectAssertions` rather than `GenericObjectAssertions`), so it can't chain the type information to later calls.

I think this is a flaw in the library design, personally, but it is easily worked around by substituting `.NotBeNull()` with `.BeOfType<T>()` as so:

```cs
result.Should().BeOfType<ThingWithLink>() // assertion fails if `result` is null
    .Which.Link.Should().Be("https://someinvoiceurl.com");
```

Of course, if you assert on your `ThingWithLink` type a lot, it could be worth writing a custom assertion so that you can be "more fluent":

```cs
result.Should().BeOfType<ThingWithLink>()
    .And.HaveLink("https://someinvoiceurl.com");
```

If you need something more ad-hoc, you can always just use `.BeEquivalentTo()` to do structural comparison:

```cs
result.Should().NotBeNull()
    .And.BeEquivalentTo(new { Link = "https://someinvoiceurl.com" }); // ignores all members on `result` except for `result.Link`
```

Comment: `.BeOfType<T>()` will fail if is null?

Comment: Correct: `null` has no runtime type, so it cannot be of type `T`.